# Max flow with minimum number of edges

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms

A max-flow problem may have multiple solutions. Among these max-flows, I seek the one with the minimum number of positive flow edges (by positive flow edges I mean the edges carrying positive flow). How can I design an algorithm finding such flow?

Comment: I do not know the answer to this question, but I'd like to add that the same problem for general linear programs (that of minimizing the nonzero variables in an optimal solution) is NP-hard. Wikipedia calls this the "minimum relevant variables in linear system" problem.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4432789/966819. In the given reduction, minimizing vertices is equivalent to minimizing edges.